# Conditional IF/ELSE statements in iOS Constants File

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, constants

Fellow Coders...

- I have server url's set up in my application's **global constants file**.
- I also have a variable called **"DebugMode"** in my application plist that once switched should change the urls the application will be using.

**Constants.h** 
extern NSString * const LOGIN_URL;

**Constants.m** 
NSString * const LOGIN_URL = @"http://www.url.com";

Anyway I can replicate the following psuedo code below into Objective C?

```
if([[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"DebugMode"] boolValue] == NO)
{
  NSString * const LOGIN_URL = @"http://www.production-url.com";
}
else
{
  NSString * const LOGIN_URL = @"http://www.qa-url.com";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your asking for isn't exactly possible (at least not in the way your asking for). A constant is setup and established whilst compiling (not strictly true, but for the sake of this explanation, it will do) and thus means that it can not be mutated for any reason at runtime.

The traditional way of changing the values of constants depending on debug and release code is through the preprocessor. Like so:

```
#if __DEBUG_MODE__ == 1
    NSString * const LOGIN_URL = @"http://www.qa-url.com";
#else
    NSString * const LOGIN_URL = @"http://www.production-url.com";
#endif
```

Now `__DEBUG_MODE__` needs to be defined before it can do anything, and there are a few ways you could do this. You could add the following line to you prefix header file (.pch)

```
#define __DEBUG_MODE__ 1  // Change to 0 to disable debug mode.
```

or add the compiler flag `-M__DEBUG_MODE__=1` to the file you wish to effect. This means that whenever `__DEBUG_MODE__` is set with a value of 1, the compiler will use your debug constant, and when it has a value of 0 the compiler will use the production constant.

This also has the benefit of keeping debug and production code separate (you should avoid having both in your binary as it can open a whole world of problems and security issues).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tom, so there is no way I can have a conditional in the Constants.m file where I am actually setting the constant? Meaning, I am not trying to change the constant after I have set it, I am trying to do the conditional before the settings of the constant.

Comment: As I said, not directly. The problem comes from the if keyword/construct being actual executable code which requires a current stack frame, and the idea of a global constant is that it exists outside of a stack frame, and in the applications constant data store. This is the reason why this kind of thing is done at compile time through the preprocessor. I'd strongly suggest reading up about the preprocessor and what it is and can be used for. It can be a really powerful tool when used correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I've had a situation like this I've just created a class method in my constants file:

```
+ (NSString *)loginURL {

    if([[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"DebugMode"] boolValue] == NO){
        return @"http://www.production-url.com";
    }
    else {
        return @"http://www.qa-url.com";
    }
}
```

It also makes it more clear in your code that as the `loginURL` string is coming via a method, it may be dependent on a run time condition:

```
NSURL *loginURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[Constants loginURL]];
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I had this in mind, but I have everything in one constants file for better organization and was hoping I can achieve the same thing within the actual constants file.